# Moto 360 GoogleApiClient onconnectionFailed() : INTERNAL_ERROR (errorCode : 8)

Tags: android, wear-os, google-api-client, nexus-7, moto-360

I'm developing an *Android* and *Android Wear* app where I use **`GoogleApiClient`** to communicate between **Moto 360** smartwatch an **Nexus 7** tablet. Everything worked fine, until now. When I install my application to my smartwatch, the connection to the Google Api failed, and in my `onConnectionFailed()` method I get this error above.

I used `GooglePlayServicesUtil`'s `getErrorDialog()` method to get the error's text on watch:

> GestureControl is having trouble with Google Play services. If the
>   problem persists, please contact the developer for assistance.

I already tried to *factory reset* my Moto 360, and *reinstall* the Android Wear on my Nexus 7, but it didn't help.

Anyone some help?

Comment: Please post the code you're using to attempt connection to `GoogleApiClient`.

Comment: here's the code of watch:
 `mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                                  .addApi(Wearable.API)
                                  .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                                  .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                                  .addApi(AppIndex.API).build();`

+ in onResume(): 
`mGoogleApiClient.connect();`